# Python COM server throws 'module' object has no attribute 'VARIANT'

Tags: python, com, com-server

Here is a COM server implemented in Python:

```
from win32com.server.exception import COMException
import pythoncom
import sys
import os
from string import Template
import logging
import logging.config

class Connector:
    _reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    _reg_clsid_ = "{0CE25AEB-1AFA-4DA7-97BD-F93CDBFB376C}"
    _reg_desc_ = "Python Test COM Server"
    _reg_progid_ = "Compy.Connect"
    _public_methods_ = ['Process', 'Status']
    _public_attrs_ = []
    _readonly_attrs_ = []

    def Process(self, what):
        pass

    def Status(self):
        return Template("""
        Current Directory: $dir
        Installed: $script
        PythonPATH: $pyPath
        """).substitute(dir = os.getcwd(),
                        script = os.path.abspath(__file__),
                        pyPath = sys.path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Connector)
```

It registers ok.
When it is run it causes the following to occur on the production machine but NOT on the development box:

```
>>> cc = CreateObject("Compy.Connect")
>>> cc.Status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\dynamic.py", line 42, in _
_call__
    return self._obj._comobj.Invoke(self._id, *args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 717, in Invo
ke
raise COMError(hresult, text, details)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (u"Unexpected Python Erro
r: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VARIANT'\n", u'Python COM S
erver Internal Error', None, 0L, -2147467259))
>>>
```

I have installed comtypes 0.6.2. Running Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VARIANT class was introduced in Pywin32 build 217.
Try installing the latest version on the machine that
it's failing on.